# ThreeJS Inconsistent Lighting

Tags: three.js

I understand that this can be really complicated to debug, given that there are a lot of objects with different properties, but I'm hoping that there is a common pitfall that can cause PointLights in THREE to shade inconsistently.

[image: wonky lighting]

In the picture above I have cubes with MeshLambertMaterial materials. Each cube shares the same model but has it's own material (in case i want to change the colors dynamically). The lights are the yellow splashes.

However cubes have differing shading effects.

1. a nice gradient shade
2. a blue luminescent glow

And you can see that the bright blocks suddenly drop off near the bottom.

Can anyone give me pointers to find why my shading is inconsistent?

Comment: 1. Can you assign the same material to each cube and see what happens? 2. Are you using your custom geometry or the THREE.BoxGeometry()?

Comment: I can (I'll post results later), and i'm just using THREE.CubeGeometry

Comment: Exactly the same effect using the same material :(

Comment: If i add the light at the beginning, it will illuminate more objects than if i add it later. Why would that be?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem for me is that THREE's way of storing colors is float based. (0.0 - 1.0) and i was setting some of the colors integer based (0 - 255). THREE didn't complain so it made some colors stronger and thusly the light affected them differently.